# Running nunit-console on a solution file leads to System.IO.FileLoadException

Tags: nunit, nunit-console

When I try to use nunit-console.exe to run all the tests in a solution file as such:

`nunit-console.exe MyProject.sln`

I get the following exception (shown below).  However when run the console runner on ANY of the projects in my folder structure, the runner works just fine and never gives me the following exception.  I also am pretty certain that the version of the nunit library that I am linking to is the same as the runner that I am using.  Also, my solution doesn't reference any projects that are outside the directory structure containing my .sln file.

Does anyone have any clue what I can do!? :(

Thanks!
Phil

```
NUnit version 2.5.10.11092
Copyright (C) 2002-2009 Charlie Poole.
Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
All Rights Reserved.

Runtime Environment -
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.1 ( Net 4.0 )

ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Default
Execution Runtime: net-4.0
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=2.5.10.11092, Culture=neutral, Pu
blicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the
 assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'nunit.framework, Version=2.5.10.11092, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77'

Server stack trace:
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount,
IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInsta
ntiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandle(Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHa
ndle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethod
Arguments)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope
, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilte
rType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMeth
odInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken,
 Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecorate
dTargetSecurityTransparent)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
   at NUnit.Core.CoreExtensions.InstallAdhocExtensions(Assembly assembly)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Load(String path)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, Boolean autoSuites)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, String testName, Boolean autoSuites)
   at NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.Build(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.SimpleTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.RemoteTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server,
 Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExec
uteInContext)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at NUnit.Core.TestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.TestDomain.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.ConsoleUi.Execute(ConsoleOptions options)
   at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main(String[] args)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.

Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the [Fusion Log Viewer](http://automaticchainsaw.blogspot.com/2007/11/debugging-with-fusion-logger.html) to see what assembly is failing to load.  It should tell you not only what file it is failing on, but where it tried looking for that file.

Comment: Ah!  This tool is magic! Thanks Pedro :)  It turns out we are using a 3rd party software that included a nunit dll that was a different version than ours.  And nunit was finding that dll before finding ours.

As we don't need to run nunit on this 3rd party software, we just deleted their version of the dll.  I would be interested to know if there is a better way around this, but for now, I am content.

Answer (score 2):

In my case `nunit-console.exe` did not respect the assembly redirection from `web|app.config`. unless you provide **`/domain=multiple`**

My Problem:
EntityFrameworkTesting.Moq -> requests Moq, Version=4.2.1409.1722

I had already a newer assembly referenced.

**The solution** for me was to add **`/domain=multiple`** parameter. see the [NUnit docs](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.6.3)

**So I run:**

```
D:\tools\NUnit-2.6.4\bin\nunit-console.exe %SOLUTION_PATH%\Project.sln /config:Release /framework:net-4.0 /domain=multiple /xml=nunit-result.xml
```